# shell script to store text file into arrays and print it out

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, sorting

E.G the text file from user consist of:

```
monkey horse     monkey  lion
lion horse 
monkey
```

how do i sort it into array and print it out one by one with shell script and become:

```
monkey 
horse
monkey
lion
lion
horse
monkey
```

?

thanks!

Comment: please show your best attempt to solve your problem as StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. Also you should explain if you really need arrays, as there is nothing in your output that suggests an array is needed. Also, your title says "store text file", while the body of your Q says "how do i sort it". Edit your Q to clarify your needs (please don't reply in comments). Good luck.

Comment: Uh `arr=( $(< filename) ); for i in ${arr[@]}; do echo "$i"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comment, you can rely on the default `IFS` (internal field separator) to separate the values into individual array elements. Nothing more than a 1-liner is needed:

```
$ arr=( $(< filename) ); for i in ${arr[@]}; do echo "$i"; done
```

**Example**

With your data saved in a file called `dat`:

```
$ arr=( $(< dat) ); for i in ${arr[@]}; do echo "$i"; done
monkey
horse
monkey
lion
lion
horse
monkey
```